# inlining C code : -flto or not -flto

Tags: c, gcc, clang, gcc-warning

One of my recent program highly depends on inlining a few "hot" functions for performance. These hot functions are part of an external `.c` file which I would prefer not to change.

Unfortunately, while Visual is pretty good at this exercise, gcc and clang are not. Apparently, due to the fact that the hot functions are within a different `.c`, they can't inline them.

This leaves me with 2 options :

- Either include directly the relevant code into the target file. In practice, that means `#include "perf.c"` instead of `#include "perf.h"`. Trivial change but it looks ugly. Clearly it works. It's just a little bit more complex to explain to the build chain that `perf.c` must be there but not be compiled nor linked.
- Use `-flto`, for Link Time Optimisation. It looks cleaner, and is what Visual achieves by default.

  The problem is, with `-flto`, gcc linking stage generates multiple warnings, which [seem to be internal bugs](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51744) (they refer to portion of code from within the standard libs, so I have little control over them). This is embarrassing when targeting a "zero warning" policy (even though the binary generated is perfectly fine).

  As to clang, it just fails with `-flto`, due to packaging error (error loading plugin: LLVMgold.so) which is apparently very common accross multiple linux distros.

2 questions :

1. Is there a way to turn off these warning messages when using `-flto` on gcc ?
2. Which of the 2 methods described above methods seems the better one, given pro and con ?
3. Optional : is there another solution ?

Comment: Normally files containing inlined functions are given a `.inl` extension, and #included at the bottom of the corresponding header.

Comment: The bug report says it has been fixed. Is it an option to try with the latest binutils?

Comment: Please state the versions of the tools.

Comment: @blueMoon : not really. Solving the situation just for me is not an option. It should work for other teams with different build chains, which I don't control, so it's not possible to depend on a too specific version. Besides, there is also the pb of clang ...

Comment: @olaf : I have tested with gcc 4.8.4 and clang 3.4. But as said in an earlier comment, I need to support broader configurations.

Comment: "Borader configurations" does not necessarily include old compiler versions. Try LTO with 4.7.2 and you will also encounter problems. Somewhere you eventually will have to make a cut.Note, however I asked about "the tools", which is not just the compilers. How about binutils? Note that LTO requires to invoke the linking stage with exactly the same options as use for compiling. Also it does require _all_ parts to be LTOed to be appropriately compiled. Not sure about stdlib from standard install (this is normally dynamically linked)..

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'll have to support gcc 4.4, clang 3.2 and visual 2010. Maybe even older. If I have problems to setup a "right config", then it's going to be even worse for my users. I'm not going to play with strange configs and tell my users to do something disrupting on their system. Either it can be safely embedded and automated into a Makefile, or it's a no go. On these premises, @Sneftel's answer looks closer to the mark.

Comment: Depending on the size of the project, you could also use an "amalgamation" build for release builds similar to what sqlite does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment you have to suport gcc 4.4. As LTO started with gcc 4.5 (with all caution about early versions), the answer should be clearly. **no `-flto`**.

So, `#include` the code with all due caution, of course.

Update:

The file-extension should not be `.c`, though, but e.g. `.inc` (`.i` is also a bad idea). Even better: `.h` and change the functions to `static inline`. That still might not guarantee inlining, but that's the same as for all functions and it maintains the appearance of a clean header (although a longer `inline` function still is bad style).

Before doing all this, I'd properly profile, if the code *really* has a problem. One should concentrate on writing readable and maintainable code in the first place.